# Implement custom value in YvalueMemeber in chart using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, bar-chart

I have an issue when implementing a chart column this my code below:

```
string CmdString = " SELECT convert(varchar,avg(DATEDIFF(second,[DateOuverture],[DateCloture]))/(86400)) + 'D:'+ 
                                 convert(varchar,avg(DATEDIFF(second,[DateOuverture],[DateCloture]))%(86400)/3600) + 'H:'+
                                 convert(varchar,avg(DATEDIFF(second,[DateOuverture],[DateCloture]))% 3600)/60)+'M:'+convert(varchar,avg(DATEDIFF(second,[DateOuverture],[DateCloture]))%60) +'S' as Time,A FROM table group by A";
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
           myCommand.Connection.Open();
           SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
Chart4.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "A",myReader,"Time" );
```

Example:

```
Time(9D:1H:25M:47S,13D:0H:56M:27,15D:0H:8M:24S)                   

A(MAMMO,SCINTIGRAPHIE,STANDARD)
```

I wish display A in `XvalueMemeber` and Time in `YValueMemeber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be more specific and maybe post some of your code.

Anyway, this is the way I bind a `Chart`.

To get the datasource for your `Chart` you need to fill the `DataSet` and then take data from one of its DataTables.

```
// by index:
DataTable firstTable = dataSet.Tables[0];

// or by name:
DataTable firstTable = dataSet.Tables["Table1"];

DataView dv = firstTable.DefaultView;
```

Then bind the Chart with the DataView:

```
Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
// Some other initialization for the Chart...
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(dv, "X_COLUMN", dv, "Y_COLUMN");
```

**- EDIT -**

You can try to move your Time cast from integer seconds amount to string (DD:HH:...), from query level to code level, inside `Chart.Customize` EventHandler.

```
protected void Chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var label in Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels)
    {
        int secondsAmount = int.Parse(label.Text);
        string timeString = "";
        // Insert the conversion logic here and get the timeString...
        label.Text = timeString; // with format DD:HH:MM:SS
    }
}
```

This way, the integer value is used to get the proportional size of the bar (or line, or whatever...) on the chart and then the visible label is converted from the seconds amount to something that is more "humanly understandable".

Comment: i get this Error cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Which line of code gives you that error? Please post your code update.

Comment: Chart4.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(ds, "A", ds, "Time");

Comment: The `DataBindXY()` method needs a `System.Collections.IEnumerable` object. You can't pass it a `DataSet` object. You need to extract data from one of the `DataTable` of your `DataSet` and then pass those data in an `IEnumerable` form (such as a `DataView`) to the method. Please consider that the `DataTable` object has a property called `DefaultView` that returns a `DataView`. **Look at answer edits.**

Comment: okey, i changed dataset to datareader(Chart4.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "A",myReader,"Time" );) ..there is no error but the chart is empty ..i wonded if Yvalue can have a string values !! because Time is in string and A too

Comment: I'm going to take a closer look to some applications I made. For now, did you tried to set `Series.XValueType` and `Series.YValueType` properties to see if there's an option to match your type? This is an example for `DateTime`: `Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
System.DateTime x = new System.DateTime(2008, 11, 21);
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(x.ToOADate(), 34);`. I think you should not convert `DateTime` to `String`...

Comment: my field Time is an integer (date end - date start)  i want display it as day:hour:minute: second it's more siginifical to user better than seconds that why i converted to string (see my code in the top)